# strong property in Xcode without ARC?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, automatic-ref-counting

When I run Xcode 4.5 , By default it is with ARC Off stage.But When we create Xcode project
Strong property comes instead of Retain.

1)If Strong and weak related to ARC , why is it coming in non-Arc project?

2)If Both strong and retain are same, If I change the keyword retain to strong in earlier
xcode versons for non-Arc projects,will it work correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `strong` is just a synonym for `retain` when not using ARC - it's included in non-ARC projects by default to minimize the changes needed when converting between ARC and non-ARC, since `retain` doesn't work with ARC but `strong` works with both project types.

Also, yes, if you change it to `retain`, that won't break your code.

Comment: should I release strong property as retain property in dealloc?

Comment: @mirdad yes. More precisely, you should either set it to nil or release the backing ivar. Don't release properties directly.

Comment: it seems (at least on the latest Xcode) that if the property is of block type, `strong` does `copy` in non-ARC

Answer (score 0):

In addition to H2CO3 answer´s: xCode will not warn you about this situation. Indeed, if you are adding this class from ARC implemented project , remember to implement `-(void)dealloc()` method and release delegates in case of protocol implementation.